# CMake doesn't build project with wmain

Tags: c++, cmake, unicode

I am developing small programs for personal training of C++ features. When I have an entry point of `main` everything is fine, when I bulid with `wmain` I get this in terminal:

```
[build] /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
[build] (.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
```

I am using:

System: Manjaro Linux 23

IDE: Code OSS

Language: C++

Build System: CMake 3.27.8

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(CMake_Project VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)


include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True) 

add_executable(CMake_Project Odd_Element.cpp)
add_subdirectory(UOutput)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Comment: `wmain` is a Microsoft thing, you are not using a Microsoft compiler (or even using Windows). I suppose the real question is why you want to use `wmain` in the first place.

Comment: For Linux everything should be in UTF-8 already, no need for wide characters.